# wowhead_tooltips inside Angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using Laravel 5 with angularjs Trying to loop through jsonp reply showing World of Warcraft **wowhead_tooltips** and have come to a problem I cannot decipher. Snippets included below.

wowhead script retrieves the item name and displays a tootip template for wow items. **ng-repeat prevents the item name to be displayed**, if I insert @{{topic.itemId}} the item number is displayed and the tooltip works wihtout the item name.

- The exact html block with an actual item number outside ng-repeat
  works fine. So the problem is 100% to do with ng-repeat, how can I get
  around this ?

> Laravel blade file Tooltip works outside of ng-repeat fails inside.

```html
<SECTION id="feeds"  ng-app>
        <!-- Test outside loop Works Fine  -->
        <a href="http://www.wowhead.com/item=109174"></a> <!-- Works ! -->

        <div ng-controller="FeedsController">

            <p>Guild Achievements: <b>@{{ guild_feed.achievementPoints }}</b></p> <!-- Works ! -->

            <div ng-repeat="topic in news">
                <div ng-switch="topic.type">
                    <div ng-switch-when="itemCraft">
                        @{{topic.character}} Crafted:
                        <a href="http://www.wowhead.com/item=@{{topic.itemId}}"></a> <!-- Displays nothing, however if I place @{{topic.itemId}} enclosed in a tag only the item number displays and the tootip works, uunlike above though no item name is displayed from WoWhead. -->
                        <hr/>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-switch-when="itemLoot">
                        {{--@{{topic.character}} Looted: <a href="http://www.wowhead.com/item=@{{topic.itemId}}">@{{topic.itemId}}</a>--}}
                        <p><a href="http://www.wowhead.com/item=@{{topic.itemId}}"></a></p>
                        <hr/>
                    </div>
                  
                  ... Rest of code
```

> Typical wowhead script (Works fine)

```js
    <!-- Wowhead Tooltip Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.wowhead.com/widgets/power.js"></script>
    <script>
        var wowhead_tooltips = {
            "colorlinks": true,
            "iconizelinks": true,
            "renamelinks": true
        }
    </script>
```

> My Angular js file to rereive list (Works fine)
>
> ```js
> function FeedsController($scope, $http) {
>   $http.jsonp("https://us.api.battle.net/wow/guild/dreadmaul/sons%20of%20anarchy?fields=news&locale=en_US&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK&apikey=MYKEY").
>   success(function(data) {
>     $scope.guild_feed = data;
>
>     $scope.news = data.news;
>   });
>
>
> }
> ```